# Google cloud app engine deployment: worker failed to boot

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am relatively new to google cloud. I am trying to run my codes in google cloud by deploying them through app engine. From GC SDK prompt, after deploying, it shows done and not showing any error. However when checking with "gcloud app browse" to see if it is running or not, it shows 502 bad gateway".

The log shows "worker failed to boot".
What can cause the problem and how to resolve it?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you include your `main.py`, `app.yaml`, and any other relevant code?

Comment: @DustinIngram its solved now, there was a google credential mismatch. Thanks anyway :)